# How to assign default value in mysql Storedprocedure

Tags: mysql

How to assign the Default in stored procedure for MySQL

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`ntc`@`%` PROCEDURE `MangerModule`()
BEGIN
    select (select sum(AmountRecevied) from collection) as TotalAmount,
           (select  @DayAmount := sum(AmountRecevied) as TotoalAmountperday 
            from collection  
            where  day(Date_Time)= day(CURRENT_DATE())) as Dayamount,

           (select  @MonthAmount :=sum(AmountRecevied) as TotoalAmountperMonth  
            from collection 
            where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') 
                and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month )) as monthamount,

           (select  @YearAmount := sum(AmountRecevied) as TotoalAmountperYear  
            from collection  
            where  year(Date_Time) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) as yearamount;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IFNULL`:

```
select (select IFNULL(sum(AmountRecevied), 0.0) from collection) as TotalAmount,
       (select  @DayAmount := IFNULL(sum(AmountRecevied), 0.0) as TotoalAmountperday 
        from collection  
        where  day(Date_Time)= day(CURRENT_DATE())) as Dayamount,

       (select  @MonthAmount := IFNULL(sum(AmountRecevied), 0.0) as TotoalAmountperMonth  
        from collection 
        where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') 
            and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month )) as monthamount,

       (select  @YearAmount := IFNULL(sum(AmountRecevied), 0.0) as TotoalAmountperYear  
        from collection  
        where  year(Date_Time) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) as yearamount;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: I don't get an error when I try my SQL with your data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22b82/2